# groovysh throws javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I'm trying to use groovysh to interactively develop some code, but when I start groovysh with the application classpath, I get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.xml.FactorySupport$2.run(FactorySupport.java:56)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

It seems there is some version conflict between my application dependencies and the groovysh dependencies.  Is there a work-around that does not require carving up my application classpath?

Comment: I am having the same problem when invoking groovyConsole :( Did you find a way to solve it @kevin?

Comment: How are you loading your classpath into the shell/console?